# react-native-video onTimedMetadata not working in android

Tags: react-native, metadata, internet-radio, react-native-video

```
  import Video from 'react-native-video';
  const radioUrl = 'https://edmradio.ru/edm';

  <Video
        source={{
          uri: radioUrl,
        }}
        repeat={false}
        paused={!isPlaying}
        muted={isMuted}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
        onLoad={event => {
          handleVideoLoad(event);
        }}
        onTimedMetadata={event => {
          const parts = event.metadata[0].value?.split('-');
          setTrackName(parts[1]?.trim());
          setArtistName(parts[0]?.trim());
        }}
      />
```

This is code, Here i'am using react-native-video to play the radioUrl and collecting the metadata like artist name and track name by onTimedMetadata functionality.

In IOS, the metadata is fetched through onTimeMetadata,but its not working in android

In android,How to extract the metadata of the radioUrl using react-native-video library.

Is there any library available to extract the metadata like track name,artist name from an internet radio url in react native

Or

Is there any radio player in react native that can stream using this radioUrl and should able to mute/unmute and get the metadata also